# Membership Type change from Fixed to Rolling

Tags: civimember

I'm working with an organization that decided to change their membership types from fixed to rolling. The member data was imported from an outside source. I set up a membership type "Regular-F" to attach to those members who were imported. 
To change to rolling memberships for NEW members, I set up a second membership type "Regular" that is a rolling membership based with a start-date of when the membership was taken and an end date 12 months later. 
Here's the problem: when a member has a membership of Regular-F and renews using the online form, the membership type of Regular-F is retained. I can manually change to Regular by editing the membership record, but I'd like to have a Regular-F membership automatically change to Regular upon renewal. 
Is it possible? What happens if I disable the membership type Regular-F?
Is a batch change feasible?
thanks, 
Kate

Comment: How many memberships are we talking? You could do a batch update via profile to speed up the process of changing them over. I believe the 'membership import' gui uses membership type as a match field so I don't know that importing that way would work.

Comment: There are several hundred that would need to be changed and I tried a batch update, but was unable to construct a profile that contains and ID, name, email, membership type and membership status since these fields come from different types - contacts, individuals, membership, etc.  Any other thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: My thought was that you could create a profile that was only the "membership type" field, and search up the memberships you need to change (something like search for memberships of regular-f type). You can batch update via profile 100 at a time, it would be faster because you can just hit "tab tab f" or something like that a bunch of times to change the types when they're all in one list. Other information that isn't a "match to" category could be done by bulk import matching on the membership IDs.

Comment: That should work fine - if i want to make global changes from Regular-F to Regular. I'm not sure if the client wants to do that. I'll check but I don't see why not unless the change will affect the start/end dates for membership renewals.